# Ordenar por coluna JSON profunda

Tags: mysql, json, order-by

Tenho uma coluna chamada `data`, que tem, por exemplo, esse JSON

> `[{"name": "unit", "value": "2", "validator": ["required"]}, {"name": "name", "value": "teste", "validator": ["required"]}]`

Eu preciso fazer um `SELECT` que ordene pelo `"value"` quando o `"name"` (`key JSON` dentro do `Array`) for `name` (valor), ou seja, nome da pessoa em questão.

Como eu poderia fazer isso? É possível? **MySQL 5.7.19**